# getting text of an html file from tika parser in solr

Tags: html, solr, apache-tika

I am trying to automatically index html files using Solr 6. The solrconfig.xml file looks like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
              startup="lazy"
              class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="lowernames">true</str>
  <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
  <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

This is the default configuration. I don't understand how Tika produces the `fmap.content` field.

for example, the output of the command `./bin/post -c myexample -params "extractOnly=true&wt=ruby&indent=yes" -out yes docs/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html`

produces the following output:

```
{
  'responseHeader'=>{
    'status'=>0,
    'QTime'=>12},
  ''=>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta
name="stream_size" content="869"/>
<meta name="X-Parsed-By"
            content="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/>
<meta
name="X-Parsed-By"
            content="org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"/>
<meta
name="stream_content_type" content="text/html"/>
<meta name="dc:title"
            content="System Requirements"/>
<meta
name="Content-Encoding" content="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="Content-Type-Hint"
            content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta
name="resourceName"
            content="/home/szr163/search441/indexer/solr-6.3.0/docs/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html"/>
<meta
name="Content-Type"
                content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>System Requirements</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>System Requirements</h1>

<p>Apache Solr runs on Java 8 or greater.</p>

<p>It is also recommended to always use the latest update version of your Java VM, because bugs may affect Solr. An overview of known JVM bugs can be found on <a
                shape="rect" href="http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/JavaBugs">http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/JavaBugs</a>
</p>

<p>With all Java versions it is strongly recommended to not use experimental <code>-XX</code> JVM options.</p>

<p>CPU, disk and memory requirements are based on the many choices made in implementing Solr (document size, number of documents, and number of hits retrieved to name a few). The benchmarks page has some information related to performance on particular platforms. </p>

</body>
</html>
',
  'null_metadata'=>[
    'stream_size',['869'],
    'X-Parsed-By',['org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser',
      'org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser'],
    'stream_content_type',['text/html'],
    'dc:title',['System Requirements'],
    'Content-Encoding',['UTF-8'],
    'Content-Type-Hint',['text/html; charset=UTF-8'],
    'resourceName',['/home/szr163/search441/indexer/solr-6.3.0/docs/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html'],
    'title',['System Requirements'],
    'Content-Type',['text/html; charset=UTF-8']]}
```

Is `<meta name="stream_size" >` a tag that will be interpreted by Solr as the field `stream_size` and the `content` for that tag will be considered as the value? Why is the text from the html not within any such tag?

Answer (score 0):

The example techproducts config set includes

'a copyField directive that causes all content to be indexed in a predefined "catch-all" *text* field, to enable single-field search that includes all fields' content.'

Maybe you can compare your config with the techproducts config, and understand it better. Otherwise you would need to show more of your config.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schemaless+Mode

Yes, clearly you would get a Solr field named stream_size with a value of 869. But as you have it, you have 'extract_only' which just parses the file and does not index it.